# what is headMeta() in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am a beginner of Zend framework. I am just practicing with few tutorial projects. In some project I have found the below codes in layout.phtml but I don't understand what is the purpose of these codes.

```
 <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?> 
 <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
```

Please explain the above two lines.

Thanks
Enamul

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headmeta

Comment: how to accept ? I am searching for accept button but not found

Comment: u see `tick mark` below the voting arrow?

Comment: There is a tick icon near to the answers of your question click on the most suitable one

Comment: But i don't see any tick icon :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to start accepting some questions first before asking

```
<?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?> //This will be in your layout/phtml file,giving the title
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?> // Giving any meta info
```

The purpose of adding this is say you have two controllers FooController and BarController .You want to give title foo to the webpage while executing foo controller

```
Class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
public function init(){

$this->view->headTitle('FOO');
}

}
```

In the same way you can give different title for another controller also

```
Class BarController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
public function init(){

$this->view->headTitle('BAR');
}

}
```

Same applies for Meta also

Answer (score 1):

Both helpers are explained in detail in the [ZF reference guide on View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html):

> *HeadMeta Helper*
>
> The HTML  element is used to provide meta information about your HTML document -- typically keywords, document character set, caching pragmas, etc. Meta tags may be either of the 'http-equiv' or 'name' types, must contain a 'content' attribute, and can also have either of the 'lang' or 'scheme' modifier attributes.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headmeta

> HeadTitle Helper
>
> The HTML  element is used to provide a title for an HTML document. The HeadTitle helper allows you to programmatically create and store the title for later retrieval and output.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headtitle

Both of them are [placeholder helpers:](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder)

> The Placeholder view helper is used to persist content between view scripts and view instances. It also offers some useful features such as aggregating content, capturing view script content for later use, and adding pre- and post-text to content (and custom separators for aggregated content).

The main idea is to have a container, which you can fill with data and then echo at some later point in your view template, e.g. with the headMeta helper you can configure various meta keywords to be inserted in your website and with the title helper you can configure the title element of the page. when you echo the helpers, they will echo their collected data all at once in a formatted way.

Please refer to the reference guide for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Its is helper class:

[HeadMeta Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headtitle)

The HTML element is used to provide meta information about your HTML document -- typically keywords, document character set, caching pragmas, etc. Meta tags may be either of the 'http-equiv' or 'name' types, must contain a 'content' attribute, and can also have either of the 'lang' or 'scheme' modifier attributes.

[HeadTitle Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headtitle)